# Using sprintf to create function arguments in C

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to create code that will pass several arrays to a sorting function that I wrote, to test the function with different corner cases.  I could just hard code the tests in, but in order to learn more C, I am trying to automate things a bit.  I thought that I could use sprintf to achieve this.  Here is code...

```
//test array - smallest number is last
int array1[] = {44,23,11,57,90,101,20,5};

//test array - smallest number is 2nd
int array2[] = {5,4,44,23,11,57,90,101};

//test array - smallest number is first
int array3[] = {4,11,44,23,5,57,90,101};

char test[7];
int number_arrays = 3;

for (int test_number = 1; test_number <= number_arrays; test_number++)
{
    sprintf(test, "array%i", test_number);

    printf("array before sort:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        printf("%i ", test[i]);

    printf("\n");

    selection_sort(test, 8);

    printf("array after sort:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        printf("%i ", test[i]);
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get warning errors of the type "error: unused variable 'array1' "  for all three arrays.

Is this just something that cannot be done in C, or am I just totally doing it wrong, and/or completely misunderstanding the use of sprintf?

Comment: You can't do it like this - use a 2D array instead.

Comment: C is a statically typed and statically named language.

Comment: Your first `printf("%i ", test[i]);` loop accesses 8 elements of `test`, but `test` only has 7 elements (`char test[7]`). This code makes no sense.

Comment: @melpomene - `test` would be the buffer from the `sprintf` call, and therefore my intention is to have it `test[i]` to evaluate to `array1[i]`.  The `char test[7]` is to hold the string `array1` and then `array2` and then `array3`

Comment: @Brian `test` is an array (of characters). `test[i]` is the i'th element of `test`. In order these elements are `'a'`, `'r'`, `'r'`, `'a'`, `'y'`, `'1'`, `'\0'`, `<error: out of bounds>`.

Comment: Ultimately, you're just doing it totally wrong — you can't do what you're trying to do directly.  Given that the array names are global variables (visible outside this source file), you could play games with dynamic loading (e.g. POSIX [`dlopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlopen.html) and [`dlsym()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html)
 — Windows has different functions for the same job; so do some other Unix-based systems).  But that is pretty contorted and a sledgehammer to crack a nut.